# Python: how can I save all the lists of pixels in only one excel file without overwriting the outcomes?

Tags: python, dataframe, image, for-loop, overwrite

I am not super good at programming so sorry in advance if my question sounds stupid, but I can't figure it out.
I am working on images and I should accomplish a mathematical calculation in Python for each pixel in each image. I trasformed the images in arrays and then I applied my formula. For one image, it works well, I obtain the value for each pixel and I can save it, here the code:

```
        mu1_over_mu2 = np.divide(array_mu_low, array_mu_high)
       
        a=31.6640
        b=-41.3636
        c=20.2761
        
        Zeff=[]
        for i in mu1_over_mu2:        
            x = (a) + (b * i) + (c * (i**2))
            Zeff = + x                                     
        
        print (Zeff)
        pd.DataFrame([Zeff]).transpose().to_excel('RESULT.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

Zeff is the result I want to obtain and I save it in an excel file using Data Frame. However, when I try to work on several images, the lists are overwritten all the time and I can get only the last one. I would like to save all the lists (meaning all the pixels of all images) in only one excel file but I don't know how to do it.
Just to give you an example of my results (if I print, the outcome is correct):

```
[11.58971733 11.64090625 ......... 11.92787858 11.99986327]
[11.41248166 11.40243698 ......... 11.72714136 11.72714136]
```

I am able to save only the last list and not both (now I used two images as example, but in general I need to work on several images) because they are overwritten (I guess).

I hope my question is not too stupid, but I feel desperate :-) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are looping through images in your code but you can do something like the following.

```
df_holder = []
for image in images:
    mu1_over_mu2 = np.divide(array_mu_low, array_mu_high)
    a=31.6640
    b=-41.3636
    c=20.2761
        
    Zeff=[]
    for i in mu1_over_mu2:        
        x = (a) + (b * i) + (c * (i**2))
        Zeff = + x                                     
        
    print (Zeff)
    d = pd.DataFrame([Zeff]).transpose()
    df_holder.append(d)

final = pd.concat(df_holder)
final.to_excel('RESULT.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

Basically just loop through all the images, make a dataframe for each one and save it to a list, then concat the dataframes together and write out that to your excel file.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer! I copied only the problematic part of the code, but basically: mu1_over_mu2  is a value I calculated for each pixel and is the combination of two images (I have to merge two images and calculate the pixel ratio...for this reason I used np.divide). For the moment, changing the indentation adding a for loop doesn't work :-(